# show result dynamically in search box

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want  a search box which shows the result just below it when I click the search button without reloading the page.
for this I've js function called ShowUsers(str)
like this

```
 function showUser(str) {
 if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
       document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML =                  

   xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}
```

And a html form like this :

```
 <form>
 <input type="text" name="q"/>
 <script type="text/javascript">var x = document.getElementById("q").value;     </script>
 <input type="button" value="search" onclick="showUser(x)">
 </form>
 <br>
 <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>
```

I've one php file to show the result called as GetUser.php

I think the var x deos'nt pass to the ShowUser(str) function in the input tag I think this is not a right way to pass a js var into html event
so what can i do to show the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access **document.getElementById("q").value** directly in showUser function rather than passing x to showUser function.

```js
function showUser() {
 var str = document.getElementById("txtHint").value;
 if (str == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else { 
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) 
       document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML =                  

   xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
}
```